# Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2019

we just migrated to vs2019 and when we try to use F12/"Go To Definition" we are getting "Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret". F12 seems to work for variables that are defined inside the same file but is failing when trying to go to definitions that are in a different project.

This is happening only on some of the projects inside the same solution. both working and non working projects have the same Target Framework of 4.7.2.

all projects are still compiling properly and as far as we can tell this is the only symptom.

I have tried clearing the symbols cache, deleting the .vs hidden folder, cleaning and rebuilding the solutions. deleting the bin and obj folders and rebuilding. but no luck.

Comment: seems to be a bug that is getting tracked here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/524877/intellisense-not-working-cannot-navigate-to-the-sy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post got me close to the solution
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/505489/cannot-navigate-to-the-symbol-under-the-caret-3.html

unfortunately my package manager was not showing "Microsoft.Net.Compilers", but once I opened the vbproj files in a text editor I was able to remove the following lines:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Update "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" in Manage Nuget Packages for Solution. 
This worked for me.

Comment: Went from 1.0.0 to 2.10 and that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I was looking at a new file that was not added to the corresponding .csproj so Visual Studio didn't know how to make sense of the references located in my new file.

Double-check that your .csproj contains the file that you're experiencing this problem in.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, here is solution which worked for me.

1. Close the VS
2. Reopen as an administrator.
3. Clean the solution
4. Rebuild my solution

In between try updating the nuget package, i updated my .net core nuget package to 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler needs to be updated to the latest. I had the same issue and these are the steps I took to resolve it.

1. Right-click on "References" in the Solution Explorer
2. Select "Manage NuGet Packages"
3. Under the "Installed" tab search for "Microsoft.Net.Compilers"
4. Select "Microsoft.Net.Compilers"
5. On the side window of "Microsoft.Net.Compilers" click the update button